# Is there any method in tensorflow like get_output in lasagne

Tags: tensorflow, theano, lasagne

I found that it is easy to use lasagne to make a graph like this.

```py
import lasagne.layers as L
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = L.InputLayer(shape=(None, 3), name='x')
    self.y = x + 1

  def get_y_sym(self, x_var, **kwargs):
    y = L.get_output(self.y, {self.x: x_var}, **kwargs)
    return y
```

through the method `get_y_sym`, we could get a tensor not a value, then I could use this tensor as the input of another graph.

But if I use tensorflow, how could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with lasagne but you should know that ALL of TensorFlow uses graph based computation (unless you use tf.Eager, but that's another story).  So by default something like:

`net = tf.nn.conv2d(...)`

returns a reference to a Tensor object. In other words, `net` is NOT a value, it is a reference to the output of the convolution node created by `tf.nn.conv2d(...)`.

These can then be chained:

`net2 = tf.nn.conv2d(net, ...)` and so on.

To get "values" one has to open a `tf.Session`:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  net2_eval = sess.run(net2)
```